# Substituir jquery por javascript puro

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um script em jquery para remover uma classe de uma div de forma automática caso o javascript do navegador esteja ativado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#scriptT").removeClass("noscript");
    </script>
```

Porém para isso eu preciso importar o jquery (obviamente), no entanto essa importação ta causando conflitos com outras coisas do site que é feito com primefaces (pra quem não sabe o primefaces já possui o jquery embutido). E não dá pra usar o jquery do primefaces porque nesta página em específico não tem nenhum componente primefaces, o que faz com que o jquery não seja importado (como estou usando facelets, os links para importação vão tudo no template, consequentemente todas as páginas importam).

Enfim, dá pra substituir esse script por um em javascript puro? lembrando que tem que ser automático quando inicializa o site, sem precisar apertar botão nenhum.

O id #scriptT está na div que eu removo a classe noscript

Comment: Editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim tu não vai precisar utilizar o `onload` no *body*. No próprio *JS*, ele já vai carregar o método através do `window.onload`.

```
window.onload = removerClass();

function removerClass() {
   var element = document.getElementById("scriptT");
   element.classList.remove("noscript");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solução do Diego está correta, mas não funciona em navegadores do Internet Explorer 9 pra trás (esses navegadores não dão suporte para a propriedade `classList`).

Apenas para complementação, caso alguém precise, a forma abaixo funciona em todos os navegadores:

```
window.onload = removerClass();

function removerClass() {
   var element = document.getElementById("scriptT");
   var classes = element.className.split(" ");
   for(var x=0; x < classes.length; x++){
      if(classes[x] == "noscript") classes.splice(x, 1);
   }

   element.className = classes.join(" ");
}
```